# nuxt fully static - nuxt generate not building new data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have this scenario since I'm looking at the new fully static release recently. (https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/). I have some issues when upgrading to fully static due to my current workflow as follows:

Currently, I am calling an API before build to `populate my data` -> `npx build` -> `npx export` -> `deleting data stored`. That way, from my understanding, asyncData caches that data on the server side and it works perfectly fine on the client side. This in turn "builds" my new pages if there is new data received from my API during the `npx export` command.

However, with the new `nuxt generate`, it only builds when a change is detected in my file. The thing is that my data is populated and deleted, hence `nuxt generate` will always skip the building phase since no changes are detected -> no new pages are generated from my new data.

I am thinking of the following, but it doesn't sound ideal:

1. Run a separate js file to populate my API data -> then call `npx generate` -> then run another separate js file to delete the API data, so that whenever `npx generate` runs, it detects the data from API. But this will cause the `npx generate` to always run the build phase which isn't the intended purpose of this (?)

**MILLION DOLLAR QUESTION**

I am aware the `npx generate` is supposed to skip build for quicker "exports" and generating of pages. I am wondering if there is a better/correct way of avoiding the build (and saving time, as intended), while being able to generate my pages as new data comes in from my API.

Comment: If you have the API calls directly inside your page components (or child components of them), the new changes should be reflected as the pages will be rebuilt. The only thing "skipped" is the webpack build as no code changes.

If that's not the flow of your project right now, it'd probably make sense to adapt it 

Comment: Hey, I'm wondering if you could elaborate on how I should go about adapting my workflow of the project, perhaps a structure which will allow me to build pages from API data without rebuilding of webpack ?

Comment: As I mentioned above, this should already be the case if you fetch your data inside your components (e.g. in the page components)

Comment: Just to check, this means that if I have my API calls within `asyncData` of my page-components, when my API pulls new data, this means that the new pages will be built on `nuxt generate` ?

Comment: yes! Pages will be rebuilt all the time. The only thing that will be skipped is the *webpack build* itself.